# Why it's not displaying me the id of the child elements?

Tags: jquery

I wanted to get the child element's id using JQuery using the following technique.However, it seems the code cannot be executed in the loop..Why this is happening and how can I get each child's id?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JQuery</title>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery.js">  </script>
<style type="text/css">
#parent{width:50%;margin:auto;border:#000 thick groove;overflow:hidden;}

#child1{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#00F;}

#child2{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;margin-left:30px}

#child3{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#00F;}

#child4{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;margin-left:30px}

#child5{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#00F;}

#child6{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;margin-left:30px}

#child7{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#00F;}

#child8{float:left;width:50px;height:50px;background-color:red;margin-left:30px}
</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="parent">
<div id="child1"></div>

<div id="child2"></div>

<div id="child3"></div>

<div id="child4"></div>

<div id="child5"></div>

<div id="child6"></div>

<div id="child7"></div>

<div id="child8"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var child = $('#parent').children().length;

    var chil;
    for (i = 0;i<child;i++){

            chil = $('#parent').children()[i].attr('id');
            alert(chil);
        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might also look into jQuery's each() method. It will save you from having to write your own looping code altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`children()[i]` is returning the dom element not a jquery object so you can't call `attr` on it.  If you change it to `children().eq(i).attr` it should work.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in a much simpler way in jquery. This code could replace that whole block.

```
$('#parent').children().each(function() { alert(this.id); })
```

Comment: You mean `$('#parent').children().each`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#parent").children().each(function(index, element)
{
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#parent').children().each(function(index, value) { 
  alert($(this).attr('id')); 
});
```

Comment: @ben . oh we posted the same thing :)